# Populating list view using a JSON subarray

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following JSON url. I am trying to populate my list view using the subarrays hair[] and math[] after getting them from the JSON url.

Here is the url http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2fzqLYXj

Inside the array "Students" there is a subarray called "Properties" and another sub array inside "Properties" called "Grades". "hair" is inside "Properties" and "math" is inside "Grades".

Here is my WebService class

```
public class WebService
    {
        public WebService ()
        {

        }

        public async Task<Rootobject> GetStudentInfoAsync (string apiurl) {

            var client = new HttpClient (); 

            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(apiurl));

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response.ToString());

        }
    }
```

And here is my View Model

```
  public class Property
    {

        public int iq { get; set; }
        public string hair { get; set; }
        public string glasses { get; set; }

        public Grade[] Grades { get; set; }

    }
    public class StudentInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }

        public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

        public string StudentName {
            get{ return String.Format ("{0}", name); }
        }
//I am accessing the JSON sub arrays with the following to get the "hair" and "math" properties.

        public string[] HairColors
    {
        get
        {
            return (Properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>()).Select(p => p.hair).ToArray();
        }
    }
       public string[] MathGrades
    {
        get
        {
            return (Properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>()).SelectMany(p => p.Grades ?? Enumerable.Empty<Grade>()).Select(g => g.Math).ToArray();
        }
    }

    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public StudentInfo[] students { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And here is how I populate my list view with student names which works. Notice "StudentName" was not in a subarray.

```
var sv = new WebService();
            var es = await sv.GetStudentInfoAsync(apiurl);
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {

                listView.ItemsSource = es.students;
            });
var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof(TextCell));

            listView.ItemTemplate = cell;
            listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "StudentName");
```

But I need to populate my list view with HairColors and MathGrades as follows but the following code does not work.

```
var sv = new WebService();
            var es = await sv.GetStudentInfoAsync(apiurl);
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {

                listView.ItemsSource = es.students;
            });
var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof(TextCell));

            listView.ItemTemplate = cell;
            listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "HairColors");
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding (TextCell.DetailProperty, "MathGrades");
```

What doesn't this code work? How do I make it work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "does not work"?

Comment: What I mean is the list view is not populated with anything and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Have you tried returning a single string instead of an array? HairColors is an array, what exactly should be displayed in the cell? The first element? All elements?

Comment: Yes I can display a single item if I do listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "HairColors[0]"); What I am trying to do is populate each list item with each of the elements of the array. If I have 10 items in the HairColors array I should have 10 list view items.

Comment: That's not how the ItemTemplate works. In that case you need to use `ItemsSource = es.students.SelectMany(student => student.HairColors)`

Comment: But that doesn't populate the list. I changed it to 'listView.ItemsSource = es.students.SelectMany(student => student.HairColors)' and set binding with 'listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "HairColors");' I still get nothing.

Comment: each element of HairColors is just a string, so you would use SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, ".")

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom converter for this:

```cs
public class HairColorsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var hairColors = (string[])value;

        return string.Join(", ", hairColors);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then bind this like:

```cs
SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "HairColors", BindingMode.Default, new HairColorsConverter());
```